# How to configure and force apache to use custom logformat based on condition

Tags: apache-2.2

i'm looking for a way to force apache server to log all client info based on custom logformat.

the issue arise when there are certain website were access through a reverse proxy. so have configure the logformat to be as follow:

> LogFormat "%h %{X-Forwarded-For}i %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\"
>   \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

but the logs are not be able to be process by awstat. what i am thinking is, can we do have two logformat.

> LogFormat "%h %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
>   combined LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b
>   \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" reverseproxy

and having some variable like if else condition. for example if i see request coming from 1.1.1.1 which is my reverse proxy ip then apache need to use reverseproxy logformat.

looking for expert reply.

Answer (score 0):

You have exactly the example you need in the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#accesslog

See the "Conditional Logs" section.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you could use /usr/bin/tee

We split our ErrorLog this way (to log the errors also to syslog):

```
ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/apache2/error.log |/usr/bin/logger -t apache2 -p local1.info"
```

Comment: With `tee`, you just feed exactly the same log format into two channels. How does this help if the problem is to have two *different* log formats?

Comment: sorry, misunderstood the question.

use setenvif:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog

Comment: You can edit your answer to remove the wrong info and add the other approach.